# pubnub storage and playback history function

Tags: javascript, sdk, pubnub

is it possible to execute publish function before history function.

```
PUBNUB_demo.publish({
    channel: 'demo_tutorial',
    message: {"color":"blue"}
});

PUBNUB_demo.history({
    channel : 'demo_tutorial',
    count : 100,
    callback : function(m){console.log(m)}
});
```

for some reason history function executes before publish function is it possible to change that so publish function is executes always first

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is asynchronous so history is called before publish function completes. To do this properly, you need to call history inside of the publish success callback like this:

```
PUBNUB_demo.publish({
    channel: 'demo_tutorial',
    message: {"color":"blue"},
    success: function(){
        PUBNUB_demo.history({
            channel : 'demo_tutorial',
            count : 100,
            callback : function(m){console.log(m)}
        });
    }
});
```